# Inserting to a table when everything is parameterized

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, dynamic-sql, etl

I need to grab data stored on a remote AS/400 file system to which I connect using a linked server connection, so I can send `OPENQUERY` select statements and receive the data on SQL Server.

I don't know how many files/tables I'm going to end up with yet, but at this point I know enough to see that I'm going to need a flexible and scalable solution.... that ideally performs well enough.

So I have created a table in my `Metadata` database that looks something like this:

```
Id    Filename      FilterColumn    FilterValue    LastTransferred
 1    STDLIB.FOOBAR      TRXDATE           NULL               NULL
 2    STDLIB.SOMETH         NULL           NULL               NULL
...
```

My control flow looks like this:

```
   Collect Metadata
         ↓
[ Foreach Loop Start ]

   Execute DeleteStmt
         ↓
   Execute OPENQUERY
         ↓
 Write to destination

[ Foreach Loop End   ]
```

In the *Collect Metadata* step I have a data flow task that reads from the above metadata table and a script component that uses it to generate T-SQL statements - one to truncate/delete the existing local tables, and another to select the remote data; then I send everything into a *Recordset Destination*.

So far, so good.

The *Foreach Loop Container* iterates the recordset and can execute the generated truncate/delete commands, then executes the `OPENQUERY` select command, and dumps the *result set* into a dedicated `User::RemoteData` object variable.

And this is where I'm stumped: in the "Write to destination" step, I have another script component (configured as a "source") that takes this variable and uses an `OleDbDataAdapter` to fill up a `DataTable`, from which I'm able to pick up the column names and actual row data (every iteration of the Foreach loop container has a different table in `User::RemoteData`).

So I started implementing the `CreateNewOutputRows` override like this:

```csharp
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    using (var records = new DataTable())
    using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
    {
        adapter.Fill(records, Variables.RemoteData);
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("INSERT INTO dbo.");
        builder.Append(Variables.StagingTableName);

        var columnNames = new string[records.Columns.Count];
        for (var index = 0; index < records.Columns.Count; index++)
        {
            columnNames[index] = records.Columns[index].ColumnName;
        }

        builder.Append("(");
        builder.Append(string.Join(",", columnNames);
        builder.Append("););

        builder.Append(" VALUES (");
        foreach (DataColumn column in records.Columns)
        {
            // ok, stop, think. this can't be right.
        }
    }
}
```

So I stopped and started thinking... and I can't think of a nice, neat way to do this.

Am I going to have to script these `INSERT` commands and check column types to properly single-quote-delimit string values and whatnot?

Isn't this going to perform like a snail? I'm not liking that the Foreach container is going to process each table sequentially, and I can already see the above solution completing in *hours*... when it's only the "transfer data over from remote system" part (I have many more ETL steps coming up, that will need to consume this data).

What would be a better way? Do I have to drop the idea of sourcing my data flow from my `Metadata` database, and have `n` "statically-defined" workflows, one for each table?

Comment: Are you always essentially doing a `select *` from each table in the remote database, as that makes things very easy, or are you doing incremental ETL?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I'd love to be able to add columns e.g. to take 3 varchar columns and stage that as a date column, but I'll be happy with a select * for now =)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> // ok, stop, think. this can't be right.
> ```

Indeed, there's a better, cleaner, safer, faster way.

You have a `DataTable` in memory; you can "dump" it as-is to the destination table using a `SqlBulkCopy` object:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    using (var records = new DataTable())
    using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
    {
        adapter.Fill(records, Variables.RemoteData);

        var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null);
        bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        bulk.DestinationTableName = Variables.StagingTableName;
        bulk.WriteToServer(records);

        _transferredRows = records.Rows.Count;
        Output0Buffer.SetEndOfRowset();
    }
}
```

That fixes the first problem - you indeed don't need to be bothered with individual rows and/or column names and types, even less to build/concatenate an individual `INSERT` statement for every single row in the data source.

---

The other problem to solve is to get each iteration to run concurrently. I believe you could extract the body of the Foreach loop container into its own parameterized SSIS package, and replace it with an out-of-process *Execute Package Task*.